# Angular programmatically binding ng-model

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have an inline label which when clicked will be replaced with input box to edit the content.

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TempController">
        <label ng-model="Data" class="editable-lbl">{{ Data }}</label>
        <br /><br /> 
        <button ng-click="Save()">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is after editing, it will not update the variable inside the scope.

```
function TempController($scope)
{
    $scope.Data = 'Hi! Im enteng, Click me to edit';

    $scope.Save = function()
    {
         alert($scope.Data);
    }
}

$(document).on("click", "label.editable-lbl", function () {
     var txt = $(".editable-lbl").text();
     $(".editable-lbl").replaceWith("<input ng-model='Data' class='editable-lbl-input' />");
     $(".editable-lbl-input").val(txt);
});

$(document).on("blur", "input.editable-lbl-input", function () {
     var txt = $(this).val();
     $(this).replaceWith("<label class='editable-lbl'></label>");
     $(".editable-lbl").text(txt);
});
```

Check this fiddle for live example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vksh2wfv/)

I tried to bind ng-model in

```
$(".editable-lbl").replaceWith("<input ng-model='Data' class='editable-lbl-input' />");
```

but still when I click the save button, the same value will prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two problems:

- 1st off when you try to add any element, in your case for example: `<input ng-model='Data' class='editable-lbl-input' />` you need to <kbd>[compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)</kbd> it first by using `$compile`in order to tell to Angular to put this content under digest cycle.
- Any DOM manipulation/update write in Directives only! Otherwise you brake Angular concept

---

You can find this example helpful: <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/601/)**</kbd>

Comment: Hi, i tried it and still the data is not updating.. http://jsfiddle.net/vksh2wfv/5/ would you mind to check the sample please

Comment: oopps.. my scope:true must be false.. it is now working.. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try to put your event listeners inside the controller and then update $scope.Data instead of using jquery functions.